# Unknown levels in `f`: fct_recode error related to apostrophe formatting

Tags: r, data-cleaning, forcats

I am trying to use the `fct_recode()` command from the forcats package to relabel all the observations in a column of one dataframe to merge with another dataframe. The column I was recoding was a list of country names from a UN dataset. I coerced it to a factor and then recoded it, but for one of the country names I received the error :

> Unknown levels in `f`: Korea, Dem. People�s Rep.`

It seems to not recognize the apostrophe in the country name. I used the `anti_join()` and `unique()` commands to find which entries were not matches and even copy and pasting the name "Korea, Dem. People’s Rep." to the fct_recode gave the same error. It seems to relate to the formatting of the apostrophe, as indicated by the difference in the following lines of code:

```
undata <- mutate(undata, country_name=as.factor(country_name))
undata <- mutate(undata, country_name=fct_recode(country_name, 
                                 "Korea_North"="Korea, Dem. People's Rep."))
# versus
undata <- mutate(undata, country_name=fct_recode(country_name, 
                                  "Korea_North"="Korea, Dem. People’s Rep."))`
```

Copy and pasting either of these seemingly differently formatted apostrophes yields the same error though.

**I'm not sure how to recode it with the "correct" apostrophe.**

I'm using version 3.4.3 of R for Windows 10 and tidyverse 1.2.1.

Comment: Before any of the code above run `gsub("’", "'", country_name)`

Comment: Even running `gsub("’", "'", undata$country_name)` first yields the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problems with commas in fct_recode and have run this code beforehand, modifying a bit for your issue:

```
  undata <- undata %>%
  mutate(country_name = as.character(country_name)) %>%
  mutate(country_name = str_replace_all(country_name,
    pattern = fixed("'"), 
    replacement = "")) %>%
  mutate(country_name = as.factor(country_name))
```